# When Perl is run on Fedora17, there is no output for print statement

Tags: perl, fedora

I am trying to run Perl on Fedora17 ...

This is my perl code...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "test\n";
```

I have saved it in Desktop and was running using kconsole, perl test1.pl
I am expecting a output, 'test' in my screen...But, nothing appears..

I have asked in Fedora Support forum..Yet, want to ask the Stackoverflow community as well...

Comment: no error message as well, I tried running, perl -w test1.pl, for which again no output came...the above file was created via vi editor...when i created a perl file via fedora desktop, the file/directory not found error message I am getting, when i run via kconsole...could this be a compatibility issue?

Comment: What does `which perl` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake actually with the code and it was pointed out and the question was closed..issue is with '#' at beginning..There was an hash accidentally added by vi editor, when we run vi, on fedora17, this issue occured...it was reported to the fedora community! wondering what happnd to the comment and the answer!